# maven-shade-plugin does not include dependencies of other modules in uber jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

Summary of my issue: in a multi-module project, one of the module has a dependency to another module. When building an uber jar of this module with the `maven-shade-plugin`, all its dependencies are correctly included, but not the dependencies of the other module.

---

I have a multi-module project, with following architecture:

```
pom.xml (parent pom)
--module_1
----pom.xml
--module_2
----pom.xml
```

`module_2` has a dependency to `module_1`, declared in its pom.xml:

```
<groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>module_1</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
```

I want to build an uber jar of `module_2`, and I use the `maven-shade-plugin`, with the following declaration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This results in an uber jar:

- including all dependencies of `module_2`
- including the jar of `module_1`
- **not including** dependencies of `module_1`

Is there a way to specify to include all dependencies of `module_1` as well?

A solution I found is to use the `maven-shade-plugin` to buid an uber jar of `module_1` as well. As this jar is included in the uber jar of `module_2`, then it works. But I'd like to avoid this solution, to be able to release a simple jar file of `module_1`, not including its dependencies.

And I want to use the `maven-shade-plugin` rather than the `maven-assembly-plugin` (for its better control over files included in final jar)

---

Following request for more details by @user2321368

maven version: Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)

module_1's pom.xml where I include its dependencies: (scopes and versions are declared in the parent pom in the dependency management section)

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>other_module_I_havent_mention</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>other_module_I_havent_mention</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to use `maven-assembly-plugin`, you can have control of `classpath` if that is your concern for not using it

Comment: Are you certain this is the behavior you are seeing  i.e. have you extracted the contents of the produced uber-jar file?

Comment: The reason I ask is that what you desire is the expected behavior of the plugin, and something that I use every day.

Comment: @user2321368: yep; i have extracted the content of the uber-ja to make sure.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: no, my concern is configuration files present in dependencies that override my own configuration files. Using the maven-shade-plugin I have control on which file overrides which file.

Comment: You will still have those configuration file packed inside your assembly (may be inside jar of jar)

Comment: What version of maven are you using?  Can you include the part of module_1's pom.xml where you include its dependencies.

Comment: @user2321368 : message updated with the details you asked for.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem in the last 3 years ?